# Getting json parsing error org.json4s.package$MappingException

Tags: scala

I am trying to parse json extract elements into case class. Just curios why code is running one way and not the other way.

This code works

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods.parse

object JsonCase {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    val input = """{"InputDB: "XYZ"}"""
    case class config(stagingDB: String)
    val spec = parse(input).extract[config]
    println(spec.stagingDB)
  }

}
```

Why below code doesn't work

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods.parse

 implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    val input = """{"stagingDB": "XYZ"}"""
    case class config(stagingDB: String)
    val spec = parse(input).extract[config]
    println(spec.stagingDB)
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the opposite to be true. The second block of code works but the first fails because the quoting is wrong in `input`. There is no closing `"` for `InputDB` so it is not valid JSON.

More generally, when comparing two blocks of code you should remove as much of the shared code as possible. So `config`, `input` and `formats` should be outside the `object` and shared between both examples so that you know you are focussing on the differences in the code not the similarities.

Answer (score 0):

Everything needs to be defined at least at object/class level (it makes no sense otherwise).

Below is I think what you want

```
object JsonCase {
    // This way it applies to the whole object
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats 

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      // do stuff
      ....
```